# Using Beautiful Soup to parse unshipped orders in my amazon seller page; can't locate html tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('<my amazon seller page>', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'orders-table')
```

I am trying to scrape my personal Amazon seller central account for unshipped orders, then parse each order, and append certain data to a list.

When I run this code it returns None. Then I tried to go further up the tree to a great grandparent (some div tag) and I WAS able to grab and print that. However, when I try to go back down deeper in the tree to look for this table it doesn't show up. In addition, other tags I've tried to find deeper in the tree don't show up...it seems that not all the tags are ale to be seen.

At first I didn't use a User Agent, but adding one didn't help.

I've used Beautiful Soup a few times in the past, not an advanced user, so I'm not sure if Amazon is blocking my scraper in some way or if I'm not doing something correctly with Beautiful Soup.

Thanks

Comment: If you have access to chrome, right click the page and select "inspect element". That will open up the developers console. Find the table, then in the html source, right click it and hover over copy. Then click "copy css selector". You can pass this string to the soup.select(your_css_selector) function. I tend to find using css selectors more intuitive. maybe you will too.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but it didn't work, I get the same result as before.